# Share C code containing uint64_t between 64-bit and 32 bit systems

Tags: c, struct, 64-bit, 32-bit, keil

I am creating some C code for an intel 8052AH CPU, which I believe is 32-bits wide.  I would like to share some C code written for a PC that is 64-bits wide.

In my PC program I define a number of C structs that I would like to share with my 8052AH C code.  Obviously the uint64_t used in the structs of PC code causes a compilation error on the Keil C51 compiler.

What is the best way to share my structs?  I am thinking about creating a typedef for uint64_t that maps to char[8] on the 8052 C code.  Is there a Keil C51 specific way to do this?  Is there a better generic way to do this?

Comment: If you define your own struct or union to hold the 64-bit quantities, how will you do math?

Comment: Depends on the math needed.  But yeah.  Addition is easy: add the low words, add the carry, add the high words.  Multiplication is a little harder.  It's division that's hard.  Signed / unsigned is also tricky.

Comment: Simple XORing only, no math required.

Comment: Please post your question according to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  How do the processors share the info? it's on shared memory? is it communicated by some means?

Comment: Luis: I think you have misread the question.  There is no example code, and no info being shared between processors.  This is about sharing source code between platforms.